# Eventlistener use this

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener

Hi I have the following code:

```
popupTriggerItems[i].addEventListener('click', function(){popup('left');}, false);

var popup = function(which) {
    console.log(this);
    var id = this.getAttribute("id");
}
```

But I get this output:

> Window #
>
> TypeError: this.getAttribute is not a function

When using just popup() without an parameter the whole thing works. But I need this parameter. Why can't I access 'this' when using parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: _Why can't I access this?_ Because you don't pass it into your function neither as parameter nor as context.

Comment: You are within an anonymous function and ``this`` will be referencing the function. However, the function does not have any ``getAttribute()`` function, so the error is caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example using the `bind`:

```
popupTriggerItems[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
  popup.bind(this,'left')();
}, false);

var popup = function(which) {
    console.log(this);
    var id = this.getAttribute("id");
}
```

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

You will find more information about this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).